# Possible to override members of an inner trait?

Tags: scala, inheritance, inner-classes, overriding

Is it possible to override members of an inner trait when extending an outer class? Like

```
class Foo {
  trait Bar {
    def bar = Set("a", "b")
  }

  class Baz extends Bar
  object Baz {
    def apply() = new Baz
  }
}
```

Can I create an instance `f` of `Foo` in any form such that `f.Baz().bar == Set("c", "d")` for example?

**Clarification**: Class `Foo` is a given, I cannot change it. It calls into `Baz()`, so I also cannot change this. Thus probably it's not possible to refine override things in `Bar` or `Baz`?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Based on your clarification, it seems like what you want to do is override the object `Baz`. This is not normally possible, but you if you use the experimental compiler flag `-Yoverride-objects`, you can do the following:

```
class SubFoo extends Foo {
  class Baz extends super.Baz {
    override def bar = Set("c", "d")
  }
  override object Baz { 
    def apply() = new Baz
  }
}
```

With this `(new SubFoo).Baz().bar == Set("c", "d")`. However, if your subclass instance is typed as a `Foo`, you may get a runtime class cast exception, as in this bug: [SI-6525](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6525).

**Original Answer:**

You need to have an overridable factory method in the Foo class that can return your Bar subclass. Then in your Foo subclass, return a Bar subclass with the bar method overridden. For example:

```
class Foo {
  trait Bar {
    def bar = Set("a", "b")
  }

  def createBar = new Bar {}
}

class SubFoo extends Foo {
  override def createBar = new Bar { override def bar = Set("c", "d") }
}

scala> var foo: Foo = new Foo
foo: Foo = Foo@5ea0e5b9

scala> foo.createBar.bar
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(a, b)

scala> foo = new SubFoo
foo: Foo = SubFoo@7f8d5474

scala> foo.createBar.bar
res16: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(c, d)
```

Comment: The problem is, `Foo` is a given, I didn't design it (it is actually part of the Scala compiler framework)

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify the constraints some more. I've shown how to subclass an inner trait when extending an outer class. However, to use the subclassed inner trait, you need to instantiate it. If you can't override the code that instantiates the original trait with your new trait, there isn't really much you can do. But that doesn't really have anything to do with the fact that it's an inner trait.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new class who parent is the original Baz. Then override the definition of bar:

```
val f = new Foo { 
  class Baz2 extends Bar { override def bar = Set("c") } 
  object Baz2 { 
   def apply() = new Baz2(); 
  }
}
```

This will give you a new entry: `f.Baz2().bar` which will give you Set("c"). You will still have access to members of the original Bar trait.

As far as I can tell, you cannot override the object of your inner class. So it's hard to generate new traits on that class.

Comment: The problem is the implementation of `Foo` instantiates `Baz`, so it will not notice the different sub class

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... Which sub-class are you referring to? In the above implementation, you get all of the original Baz, but with a specific method overridden. Can you clarify what you need to work?